# "Recommend Deletion" on a question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, user-interface

When I was reviewing in the low quality posts queue, [something odd](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3527034) has struck yet again:

[image: recommend deleting a question]

I swear I did not touch anything on that question to make that happen. Does anyone know how this could happen?

Comment: How can you recommend deletion of a question?

Comment: @Braiam: exactly, that's why I'm absolutely confused.

Comment: Could you clarify: did it actually *show you* a Recommend Deletion button, or did you click something else and it recorded that way?

Comment: @animuson: I think I remember accidentally double clicking the recommend deletion button on the previous answer (but not 100% sure), but I did not see the question until I clicked back, nor did I see any of the buttons. The only reason why I found it was because the ajax section went blank another time (because it's loading), but without seeing another question.

Comment: It shows up in your review history, right?

Comment: @UndotheSnowman: yes, it shows up in my review history as "Recommend Deletion".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've added some additional server-side validation to the review queues.  It should no longer be possible to submit an invalid review result type to our server.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was animuson's theoretical case possible? or would it have encountered some checks somewhere else?

Comment: @Nick: any chance this fix has inadvertently introduced [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211429/an-error-occured-when-reviewing-this-item)?

Comment: @Matt likely, investigating

Comment: @NickCraver: The server-side checks don't address the client-side race condition, as it's still possible for the client-side code to erroneously fire a "recommend deletion" on the next item if the next item is a question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222474/race-condition-in-low-quality-audit

Answer (score 11):

For what it's worth, it's true that there is no code preventing someone from submitting a Recommend Deletion on the question. The only difference is that there's no button for it. The system doesn't actually validate responses other than "Is this a valid response for this review queue?" and "Does this response have the appropriate data associated with it?" For something like Recommend Deletion, there is no associated data (well, none that's *required*; there is a dialog box, but that submits a comment, and you can always select "No Comment" which would be equivalent to no data); it's just a button you click. Hell, even I, as a moderator, can [recommend deletion of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3527224) if I really wanted to (note I did that on a question that really needs deleted, just in case).

I'm not sure if this is intended behavior, but I'd definitely be interested in having them fix it. Theoretically if six users went around the system to recommend deletion on a question, it would probably get deleted silently by no one just like an answer, without a close reason or any indication of why it happened. That doesn't sound so good.

Comment: "*Theoretically, if six users [recommended] deletion on a question, it would probably get deleted silently...without a close reason or any indication of why it happened*" I'm going to have nightmares now.

Comment: @michaelb958 Starring Shog9 as a weird floating head version of Freddy Krueger - he's coming for... your questions! (Sorry if you now have nightmares about a floating Shog's head.)